# How to call await on azure blob service methods?

Tags: node.js, azure, express, azure-blob-storage

I am working on rename functionality for blob,as there is no way to rename blobs I am deleting the blob and creating new file with rename.however due to asyn nature sometimes blob is not getting delted and new blob gets created so i want to write async/await for both blobservices. How to achieve that as without callback it gives error?

```
module.rename=function(req,rez){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let results = await genericHandler.getUserSubscMapping();
        if (contentType != 'folder') {
            blobService.startCopyBlob(storageuri, containerName, blobName, err => {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(500).send("Error while renaming the blob");
                } else {
                    blobService.deleteBlobIfExists(containerName, oldFilePath, (err) => {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err);
                            reject(err)
                            return res.status(400).send(err);
                        } else {
                            res.status(200).json({
                                status: 'success'
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Tried code:

```
let res1 = await blobService.startCopyBlob(storageuri, containerName, blobName);//////error : Required argument callback for function startCopyBlob is not defined
```

old code where I was using call back is working fine however I want to fetch this result first then perform next oprations , searched regarding async/await on blob service but does not seem to find any article.

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the complete async/await code?

Comment: plz check if you need any other details?

Comment: Is there any sample code to achieve this? I mean wait untill operation is complete or send responce on complete?